# R: "Error: unexpected symbol in:" appears in long list of variables, but not short list

Tags: r

I am trying to get basketball stats based on a long list of variables. When I use the whole list of game_ids, I get the error referenced in the title.

Any suggestions?

```
game_ids <- c(401584434, 401584429, etc)

# Use lapply to fetch player box score data for each game
player_box_data_list <- lapply(game_ids, function(game_id) espn_mbb_player_box(game_id))

# Combine the results into a single data frame
combined_player_box_data <- bind_rows(player_box_data_list, .id = "game_id")
```

At first I thought one there was an error with one of the ID numbers, but it runs when the game_ids are run in smaller segments.

I didn't know if there was an issue with the volume of requests and also tried adding a delay, but the problem persisted.

Comment: "Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes." is a quote  taken directly from [In introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc) on CRAN. This sounds like the error you would get if your input line exceeds that limit. How are you inputting the data?

Comment: Interesting thought, @AllanCameron, that seems reasonable; if that's the case, then realize that this limit is not imposed when `source`-ing a file. If that is not it, though, jc17 please provide the real expression that triggers the error.

Comment: If @AllanCameron is right, you just need to add linebreaks (after some commas) to `game_ids`.